# Rerun (reschedule) onetime pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I've created a new **onetime** pipeline in Azure Data Factory using Copy Data wizard.

The pipeline has 4 activities and it was run just fine - all 4 activities succeeded.

Now I'd like to rerun the pipeline. So I do:

1. Clone the pipeline.
2. Change name to `[name]_rev2`.
3. Remove `start` and `end` properties.
4. Deploy the cloned pipeline.

Now the status of the new cloned pipeline is *Running*.
But no activities are executed at all.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Mmmmm. Where to start!

In short. You can't just clone the pipeline. If its a one time data factory that you've created it won't have a schedule attached and therefore won't have any time slices provisioned that now require execution.

If your unsure how time slices in ADF work a recommend some reading around this concept.

Next, I recommend opening up a Visual Studio 2015 solution and downloading the data factory that did run as a project. Check out the various JSON blocks for scheduling and interval availability in the datasets, activities and the time frame in the pipeline.

Here's a handy guide for scheduling and execution to understand how to control your pipelines.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-scheduling-and-execution

Once you've made all the required changes (not just the name) publish the project to a new ADF service.

Hope this helps